Handling multiple requests for an API originated by multiple time change of a state instantly
I am developing a dashboard in react with multiple charts and the results of
these charts can be updated based on filters (e.g. date control).
The charts useEffect hook has a dependency on date state set based on date control.
I am facing multiple issues

if a user change the date very quickly then multiple requests are originated. How can this behaviour be avoided multiple requests? I mean, does it make sense to disable filters till all the requests from different components of charts has been processed.

If yes, then how can it be achieved?

Currently, to handle multiple responses for single chart, I found a solution to get the data of last API call, using the logic below, is it correct or is there some better solution. I get this idea from react.dev -> "when to use custom hooks".

In case of multiple request the result of previous requests will be ignored.
 useEffect(() => {
    let ignore = false;
    fetch(`/api/cities?country=${country}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        if (!ignore) {
          setCities(json);
        }
      });
    return () => {
      ignore = true;
    };
  }, [country]);

